# Commit files to git hub with Windows 7 (command line)

Tags: ruby, github, commit

This is my first time committing anything to git hub and I have no clue what I'm doing. I used the 'git add .' command to add all the files in the directory I was working in. My next command was 'git commit .' and I got this screen. I cannot input anything right now to make the change go through. Anyone know what to do?

[image]

Comment: Looks like `vi`. Use `Esc` to exit insert mode and use `:x` to save and exit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've been put into vim to edit your commit message. See this [vim tutorial](http://blog.interlinked.org/tutorials/vim_tutorial.html) for some help on using the program.

Short version:

Hit `i` to enter Insert Mode (it appears you've already done this by accident, see the bottom of your screenshot). Enter your commit message. Then `esc` to switch back to "command mode", and `:wq` to save and then exit. Your commit message will be saved to a temp file, then used as input for the commit.

To avoid this in the future, use `git commit -m "This is my commit message"`. You're getting prompted (via vim) for a commit message because you didn't provide one at the prompt.

Comment: Ok, that worked and I'm out of it now. What is the command I need to use from here to push these files up to git hub, 'git push origin master'?